# RGBA not working on browsers other then Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So here's my [website](http://colourity.com). And as you can see on Chrome "Colourity" is darker where the letters overlap. I was able to get this going by using this `color: rgba(58, 184, 179, 0.78);`. Now if you look on Firefox or Safari, and pretty much any other browser. You don't see that overlap. I think it has something to do with the `0.78`. Any ideas?

Chrome:

[image: chrome]

Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Sincerely..... I don't see any difference... You are talking about mouse over? In this case, in Firefox is better than in Chrome... in Chrome the 'y' is half black and half violet on hover....

Comment: No issue here in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was trying to figure out my issue and changed `rgba` to `rgb`. You'll be able to see the overlap in Chrome now. @LucaDetomi

Comment: @user3444414 What did you expect to see?  You're using alpha channel, that's exactly what should happen.

Comment: Have you tried using just "rgb(58, ...)" and then using the opacity property separately?

Comment: Well I am trying to get the overlap on other browsers. Not get rid of it. Sorry if i'm not clear enough @Brad

Comment: I'd imagine it's a difference in rendering engine behaviour. From the looks of it, gecko composits the paths of the text before applying color... while blink applies color for each individual glyph.

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't show the overlap. @UkuleleFury

Comment: If the overlap isn't working, it's a browser bug.  Have you considered just using an image for this, to guarantee you get the look you want?

Comment: I prefer not using an image. Rather figure out why this is happening. But if I need to use an image as a fallback, I guess I'll use one. Think that having the overlap will make a difference @Brad

Comment: "I'm sorry. I was trying to figure out my issue and changed `rgba` to `rgb`" That is why we recommend using JSFiddle, instead of linking to a live site.

Comment: I guess that's kind of correct. Except the conflict was resolved Within seconds. But thanks for future reference.  @Terry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a Firefox limit.... anyway, even if not so nice... a workaround that runs is simply wrap each letter in a span tag. Somethin like this (here only for first letter):

```
<a href="http://colourity.com/" id="h1logo"><span>C</span>olourity</a>
```

---

**UPDATE May 13, 2015**

I found a [jquery plugin](http://codepen.io/jhawes/pen/JogrLZ) that has a similar behaviour. Probably CSS solution remain the best, but this is another possible solution (at least for someone)

Comment: That's nice. Very ingenious thinking. Thanks for the help.